# Molex 5039600695: What is the SIM card stopper referring to?

Tags: datasheet, sim

On some SIM card holder datasheets, I've seen references to a card stopper feature that prevents users from inserting a SIM card incorrectly. This card stopper appears to be a mechanical feature built into the body of the SIM card holder itself. [Example on page 4:](https://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/MolexmicroSIMCardSockets.pdf)

[image: Card Stopper]

The detail drawing for [Molex 5039600695](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex/5039600695/WM17882CT-ND/8572265) also refers to a card stopper. However, this particular datasheet indicates that the card stopper is 1.4mm away from the body of the SIM card holder. I am not sure how to interpret this recommended card stopper position. I understand the idea of a card stopper as a mechanical feature of the SIM holder, but not in this context of something separated from the SIM holder.

In this case, is the card stopper a distinct component from the 5039600695 SIM card holder that would need to be purchased separately?

[image]

Comment: I bet Molex would be annoyed to learn that a certain large UK telco is regularly distributing micro-SIMs that are out of spec, at 0.64mm thickness.  Although they would not be the only SIM connector vendor to be unaware of this, a certain Kyocera connector fails "card-present" detection with the thin SIMs.  It's the telco's fault though of course.  *sigh*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase "card stopper" is being used in two different ways here.

In the top drawing, it's referring to a leaf spring that only gets lifted up out of the way if the beveled corner of the SIM card is in the correct orientation. When a card is inserted incorrectly, it stops the card about halfway in. The small plastic post highlighted in green helps to support the spring while it is blocking the SIM card.

In the second drawing, it's referring to a separate mechanical stop for a **correctly-oriented** SIM card, which keeps the card from moving **out** of the connector after it has been correctly installed. This would be part of the product packaging (e.g., some sort of lid or cover).